# In which direction to round the answer, if it represents maximal population that could be infected?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm calculating the maximum number of a population that could be infected.

I have an answer of $240.0729395$.

Should I round this to $241$ because that is the max? Everyone else says $240$ is right but more than that could get infected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have proven that it is impossible for more than 240.07... people to get infected, then you have proven that it is impossible for 241 people to get infected. Thus, 240 is the correct maximum, and you should round down. Note that in this case, you should round down even if your calculated maximum is 240.99.